# Smarty replace and array

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I'm working on a site for some apartments.

I have some data getting assigned to Smarty in a foreach loop.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($obj2 as $array) {
   $smarty->assign('name'.$i, $obj2[$i]['name']);
   $smarty->assign('numbedrooms'.$i, $obj2[$i]['number_of_bedrooms']);
   $smarty->assign('numbathrooms'.$i, $obj2[$i]['number_of_bathrooms']);
   $smarty->assign('sqfeet'.$i, $obj2[$i]['square_feet']);
   $smarty->assign('deposit'.$i, $obj2[$i]['deposit']);
   $smarty->assign('rent'.$i, $obj2[$i]['rent']);
   $smarty->assign('vacantunits'.$i, $obj2[$i]['vacant_units']);
   $i++;
}
```

When the template is loaded (`$smarty->display('template.tpl');`) I want all of the data to be available via `replace`(like `replace:'[[lowestrate]]':{$lowestrate}` (example from another block of code)).

However, because the number of items in `$obj2` could change (it's currently 3), I can't just say `replace:'[[name1]]':{$name1}`. (Not to mention how long that would take)

Also, the reason replacement is required is that the page content is managed from a CMS system with a WYSIWYG editor, where the editor can type `[[lowestrate]]` to have it replaced with the lowest cost apartment.  They should be able to type `[[name1]]` to have it replaced with the name of the first apartment, or `[[numberbedrooms1]]` to be replaced with the number of bedrooms apartment 1 has.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I should go about doing this?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is a custom plugin, `preg_match`ing the contents to find the pseudo-variables and replacing them with respective variable values (`$smarty->getTemplateVars()`)

Comment: Why a foreach? Couldn't you be sending the data to smarty as an array?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job you should be doing in the PHP level, not the smarty level. I suggest that you do the replacements before the assignment to smarty, and then send the transformed array, it will be much easier (and cleaner imho)